# Oracle Data Guard - What are the changes to make on standby database which is a mirror copy of the primary database

Tags: oracle, guard, standby, dataguard

After setting up primary database which is setup with Raid1. I break the mirror and physically transfer it to the standby database hardware and did a Raid1 sync. With that I have exact replicate of the primary database on the standby database.

However, since the standby database's data is exactly the same as primary database, I have to change it to become the standby database.

example:

Primary database server oracle_sid=chicago
Standby database server oracle_sid=chicago (since its a replicated data)

I need to change the standby database oracle_sid to boston.

I believe it is not a simple case of changing the oracle_sid to boston since the database name is chicago.

Appreciate any specific and detailed steps to make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably ask this on Serverfault.  However, I'll mention here using Recovery Manager (instead of your method) to create the standby database will eliminate most of the manual work in renaming the database, recreating the control files, etc.